# Open source framework to build Web based BPMN designer

Tags: web, designer, bpmn

We have already built a BPMN designer on eclipse framework.It was easy to build with great support from eclipse based frameworks like EMF, Graphitti etc.
Now we want to build a web based BPMN designer. Can you suggest which open source frameworks i can use to do this ? I would expect the framework to support me in defining the bpmn metamodel, a graphical editor ect etc

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 4):

### Oryx / Signavio Core Components

The [Signavio Core Components](http://code.google.com/p/signavio-core-components/) are the "sucessor" of Oryx. A github mirror is available there: https://github.com/IAAS/signavio-core-components/

The Signavio Core Components switched from MIT to GPL license. Furthermore, they are unmaintaned.

#### Forks

Wapama is a fork of Oryx. It seems that https://github.com/saifulomar/process-designer is the most recently updated fork with a tight JBPM integration.

[Gemsbok](https://github.com/matthewhampton/Gemsbok) is another fork of the Signavio Core Components.

[process-designer](https://bitbucket.org/openicar/process-designer) seems to be actively maintained (as of 2013/06)

The dependency to ExtJS was removed in the context of the [Flowable](https://www.flowable.org/) project. See https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/master/modules/flowable-ui-modeler/flowable-ui-modeler-app/src/main/resources/static/editor-app/editor for the current source.

### Eclipse Stardust / Lightdust

There is also recent by the Eclipse community. Within the [Stardust project](http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/), there is a web-based BPMN Modeler, accessible via git: http://git.eclipse.org/c/stardust/org.eclipse.stardust.ui.web.git/tree/stardust-web-modeler-bpmn2. Some basic information is in the [Stardust Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Enhancing_and_Embedding_Stardust/Browser_Modeler), but no step-by-step-guide for using the web-based BPMN modeler standalone.

### Self-implemented

We made a comparison of all available web-based graph-libraries at https://ultimate-comparisons.github.io/ultimate-graphframework-comparison/.

Example code of the best ones is available at 
https://winery.github.io/javascript-graph-library-comparison/. The idea is similar to TodoMVC, but here a minimal example for graph creation is made.

(Some old comments follow)

#### jsPlumb-based

There is the project https://github.com/Dzhyrma/BPMN_Modeler, which is based on [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/). It includes [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which is a SVG-based graph-drawing library.

#### Direct canvas drawing

https://github.com/hallodom/BPMN-Modeller directly uses the 2d canvas to draw BPMN.

Answer (score 3):

http://bpmn.io/
is the best answer if the license terms (include logo) work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is already one. [Oryx](http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/). I believe some of the open source bpmn engines leverage the same.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i think Signavio uses it. But as such what i read is they have stopped supporting Oryx !

Answer (score 0):

For Stardust Web based BPMN modeller step-by-step usage, please refer to thsi link:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.analyst/html/handbooks/modelling_analyst/models/model-preface.html?cp=52_7_3

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as the content may go down or be removed in the future. Try to summarize the key points of the link in your answer instead. If you did this, I would upvote your answer.